# could any one help explaining the difference between the system DSN and user DSN?

Tags: dsn

I need to create an odbc connection to my universe database. i created one in user DSN but the output is not working well. 
could any one explain the difference so that i can understand?

Answer (score 2):

A system DSN is available to all users on the computer ('system wide'), whereas a user DSN is only available to one user.